# Django clear cache for only detail view

Tags: python, django, caching

I use redis cache backend and caching templates via django cache.
I create cache with template tag

```
{% cache 43200 object_detail object_detail.pk request.LANGUAGE_CODE %}
{% endcache %}
```

and in redis-cli I see smth like this

```
1) ":1:template.cache.object_detail.89484b14b36a8d5329426a3d944d2983"
```

My cache invalidation is a function that performed after saving object in UpdateView and takes this object:

```
def clear_cache_block(obj):
    key = hashlib.md5()
    obj_pk = obj.pk
    key.update(str(obj))
    cache.delete_pattern('*object_detail.'+str(key.hexdigest()))
```

but generated hash is not the same with hash in redis cache. 
What should I use to clear cache only for object I update?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Function responsible for creating cache key for template tag is `django.core.cache.utils.make_template_fragment_key`. It takes as first argument your cache fragment name (in this case "object_detail" and as second argument all additional arguments passed to cache tag (in this case `object_detail.pk` and `request.LANGUAGE_CODE`). It will return complete key in format: `template.cache.__YOUR_CACHE_FRAGMENT_NAME__.__HEX_DIGEST_OF_FRAGMENT_NAME_AND_PARAMETERS`

If you want to know how that hex digest is computed, check [source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.8.x/django/core/cache/utils.py#L11)

So your code should look like this:

```
from django.core.cache.utils import make_template_fragment_key

def clear_cache_block(obj, lang):
    key = make_template_fragment_key('object_detail', (obj.id, lang))
    cache.delete_pattern(key)
```

where key is language code for language that you're trying to clear cache. If you want to do it for all languages, you must do it in loop.

Answer (score 2):

To reverse cache key you need all variables that you used to generate that key. `cache` template tag ([here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/templatetags/cache.py#L45)) uses function [make_template_fragment_key](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/cache/utils.py#L11) to generate cache key.

So your cache invalidating function may look like:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.cache.utils import make_template_fragment_key

def clear_cache_block(obj):
    cache_key = make_template_fragment_key('object_detail', 
                                            (obj.id, settings.LANGUAGE_CODE))
    cache.delete_pattern(cache_key)
```

Of course if you have more languages you need to iterate over language codes and invalidate cache for each language.

Comment: Thx! It works, but function should use like this: 
make_template_fragment_key('object_detail', (obj.id, settings.LANGUAGE_CODE))